# Linear algebra and matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

prove or disprove : If A and B are 2 by 2 orthogonal matrices over R then A+B cannot be orthogonal.

OR

If S,T:R^2--->R^2 are orthogonal transformation then S+T is not an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: What have you done so far? -I will suggest to look among elementary examples of orthogonal matrices $A,B$: the more elementary, the better.   :-)

Comment: Hint: __one__ counterexample is enough!

Comment: To sohail:  I performed some very minor edits to correct some grammar and spelling, *viz* "nor Orth . . . " $\to$ "not an orth . . ."  Hope you don't mind!  If you disapprove, I will not be offended if you change it back.  Yours, RKLewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-example is given. To show that the sum of orthogonal matricies can be orthogonal take 
$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\\ -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} = ?
$$

Comment: Sorry: is this sum an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @Augusti : It is not, and so this is a counterexample to what the OP asked.

Comment: Well, the question is formulated in a negative form and makes it difficult to understand it, but as I see it, what you need is indeed a counterexample showing that indeed it IS possible to find $A, B$ orthogonal such that $A+B$ is ALSO orthogonal. Or am I completely missing the point?